# Group customers by periods in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, analytics

I can't wrap my head around this problem. I have a sample Python Pandas DataFrame that holds data on vehicles and people who owned or co-owned them at different times. There are 4 important columns:

- CREATED_ON_DT is when the record was created
- CHANGED_ON_DT is when the record was changed
- SALE_DT_KEY is when the vehicle was sold to the very first customer
- RELATION_KEY is the ownership status:

  - 9 for the former owner
  - 4 for the former co-owner
  - 3 for the current owner
  - 5 for the current co-owner

Note:

- for CREATED_ON_DT, the record does not change
- for CHANGED_ON_DT, the ownership status is given by RELATION_KEY

The way to track a vehicle sale is to get the CHANGED_ON_DT value for status 9 if the next row is also status 9.

However, the problem is that owners and co-owners can switch back and forth and the point of sale would sometimes be status 9 to status 4, which means the former owner sold the car to someone who later switched from being the owner to a co-owner.

What I'm trying to do is to capture groups of owners. For example, suppose the following persons were involved in the selling and re-selling of a car over time:

- Group 1: Person A sold an interest in a car they owned to their partner, Person B, who then became a co-owner.
- Group 2: Persons A and B then sold the car to family C which switched owners and co-owners within the family.
- Group 3: Family C then sold the car to Family D.

The following code has the sample data and my attempt to at least capture status periods. It also has a NEEDED_RESULT column.

Thank you in advance!

```
# Sample dataframe
copy_of_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "VEHICLE_KEY": [4331229, 4331229, 4331229, 4331229, 4331229, 4331229, 4331229, 4331229, 4331229],
    "PERSON_KEY": [10778254, 10778265, 20841772, 20122268, 20935263, 20962087, 21096582, 21096580, 21133677],
    "CREATED_ON_DT": pd.to_datetime(["2013-08-27 00:33:48", "2013-08-27 00:33:48", "2016-07-26 12:07:41", "2016-08-01 11:35:57", "2016-08-01 11:36:00", "2016-08-03 00:27:22", "2016-08-04 00:26:04", "2016-08-04 00:26:04", "2016-08-07 00:26:01"]),
    "CHANGED_ON_DT": pd.to_datetime(["2016-07-26 12:07:40", "2016-07-26 12:07:40", "2016-08-01 11:35:57", "2016-08-03 00:19:06", "2016-08-03 00:19:14", "2016-08-04 00:18:21", "2016-08-07 00:19:51", "2016-08-07 00:19:38", "2016-08-07 05:02:01"]),
    "SALE_DT_KEY": [20130826, 20130826, 20130826, 20130826, 20130826, 20130826, 20130826, 20130826, 20130826],
    "RELATION_KEY": [9, 4, 4, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 3],
    "NEEDED_RESULT":['group1', 'group1', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4', 'group4', 'group5']
})

# df
copy_of_df = copy_of_df.sort_values(['VEHICLE_KEY', 'PERSON_KEY', 'CREATED_ON_DT'])

# Define the status codes
current_owner = 3
former_owner = 9
coowner = 5
former_coowner = 4

# Global counter
global_counter = 0
total_rows = len(copy_of_df)

# Function to assign ownership-coownership combination
def assign_combination(group):
    global global_counter
    owner_count = 0
    last_owner_status = None
    ownership_start_date = group.iloc[0]['SALE_DT_KEY'] if pd.notnull(group.iloc[0]['SALE_DT_KEY']) else group.iloc[0]['CREATED_ON_DT']
    
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        print(f"Processing row {global_counter+1} of {total_rows}")
        
        current_owner_status = row['RELATION_KEY']
        
        
        # Check if a new ownership period starts
        if current_owner_status in [current_owner, coowner] and (last_owner_status in [former_owner, former_coowner]):
            print('3')
            owner_count += 1            
            #group.loc[group['ownership_combination'] == f'{owner_count}ownercoowner', 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {pd.Timestamp("today")}'
            group.at[i, 'ownership_combination'] = f'{owner_count}ownercoowner'
            group.at[i, 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {pd.Timestamp("today")}'
        # Check if a new ownership period starts
        elif current_owner_status in [current_owner, coowner] and (last_owner_status is None):
            print('y')
            owner_count += 1
            #group.loc[group['ownership_combination'] == f'{owner_count}ownercoowner', 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {pd.Timestamp("today")}'
            group.at[i, 'ownership_combination'] = f'{owner_count}ownercoowner'
            group.at[i, 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {pd.Timestamp("today")}'
            #ownership_start_date = row['CHANGED_ON_DT']
        elif current_owner_status in [former_owner, former_coowner] and (last_owner_status in [former_owner, former_coowner]):
            print('2')
            
            owner_count += 1
            ownership_end_date = row['CHANGED_ON_DT']
            #group.loc[group['ownership_combination'] == f'{owner_count}ownercoowner', 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {ownership_end_date}'
            group.at[i, 'ownership_combination'] = f'{owner_count}ownercoowner'
            print(ownership_start_date)
            group.at[i, 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {ownership_end_date}'
            # Reset the start date for the next ownership period
            
            ownership_start_date = row['CHANGED_ON_DT']
            
        elif current_owner_status in [former_owner, former_coowner] and (last_owner_status is None):
            print('1')
            owner_count = 1
            ownership_start_date = row['SALE_DT_KEY']
            
            ownership_end_date = row['CHANGED_ON_DT']
            print(f'{ownership_start_date} - {ownership_end_date}')
            #group.loc[group['ownership_combination'] == f'{owner_count}ownercoowner', 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {ownership_end_date}'
            group.at[i, 'ownership_combination'] = f'{owner_count}ownercoowner'
            group.at[i, 'ownership_period'] = f'{ownership_start_date} - {ownership_end_date}'
            # Reset the start date for the next ownership period
            ownership_start_date = row['CHANGED_ON_DT']
        
        print(current_owner_status)
               
        last_owner_status = current_owner_status
        
        print(last_owner_status)
            
        
        group.loc[i, 'ownership_combination'] = f'{owner_count}ownercoowner'
  
        global_counter += 1
        

    return group

copy_of_df['ownership_combination'] = None
copy_of_df['ownership_period'] = None
copy_of_df = copy_of_df.groupby('VEHICLE_KEY').apply(assign_combination)
```

Comment: Why is the third row listed as former co-owner? You put that person in group 2 but the former owner in group 2 had its sales data created after. I'm confused as to what sequence of events is being described transitioning from the first group of owners to the second or even third group of owners.

Comment: I trust my edits meet with your approval. Of course you are free to edit it further or revert to what you had previously. If you keep the changes you may wish to make the definition of Group 3 ("Family C then sold the car to Family D") more precise. For example, at the time of sale, are all members of Family C co-owners or it is owned and sold by by one member of C?. Similarly, do all members of Family D become co-owners when the car is purchased or does only one member of Family D the purchaser, and so on?

Comment: What is your expected output?